# How to get out broken piece of Plug in switch board?

Tags: electricity

I am stuck in a situation my broken plug piece stuck in a switch board while working in office as it is direct connection how easily I can remove it so that it didn't harm me?

Comment: You mean a mains plug? You *need* proper tools to do that: insulated pliers that are rated for the voltage.

Comment: A photograph of the plug and switch board would help you get more answers.

Comment: Depends on your definition of switch board. Are we referring to a switchboard as in old style  telephone operator or  something involving electrical power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with electricity you don't control, requires you to be VERY careful. Use a multimeter, find out if it's live. Even if it isn't, I agree with the insulated pliers. Before you say this is too involved, it isn't.

Find your local Harbor Freight, buy insulated pliers for $6 (https://www.harborfreight.com/8-inch-long-nose-high-voltage-insulated-pliers-96906.html), and a meter for $6 (https://www.harborfreight.com/7-function-digital-multimeter-63604.html), watch some youtube videos to learn what you're doing (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=check+an+outlet+with+a+multimeter).

**Notice**: I'm not an electrician, and I might be an idiot. Don't trust anonymous information like mine or anyone else's when it comes to your life and well-being. Get a professional or the facilities manager to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn off the electricity for that room by switching off the [circuit breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker)? These should be easily accessible in any private home. Then remove the cover of the switchboard and take out the broken plug piece.

In company buildings talk to the janitor / facility manager and let them do their job.